# Which SAE J1939 PGN number can delete an ECU in a CAN-bus network?

Tags: can-bus, j1939

I'm looking for a PGN number in SAE J1939 standard that can delete a ECU address, or at least say that this ECU address or ECU unit is not used anymore in the CAN-bus netork.

I have recently written a open source SAE J1939 library in pure C code. But I need one more PGN number. Examples are avaiable to use.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific message to remove an ECU from the network, you need to read the J1939 address claim process, once that a new ECU is connected to a J1939 network, the ECU shall broadcast and address claim message indicating the source address that its trying to claim, then if other ECU is using the same address the address claim process starts. In the internal configuration of your device you will find a serial number, vendor name , industry and more. All this information is in ASCII characters e.g "VENDORNAMESERIAL12345"´.
the address claim process is a string comparison character by character using the numeric value of the character. Once one of the characters is greater than the other the "winner" ECU keeps the source address. You can find all the information on the SAE J1939 network management and address claim sections.